# Using Postgre's lpad in EntityCore

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a query that needs a leftpad -- the issue I'm running into is when using `string.PadLeft()` it causes the query to execute in the C# code instead of as SQL.

Example:

```
response.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Number.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') == filter.Slug)
```

Is there a way in Npgsql/EntityCore to take advantage of Postgre's `lpad` function so the query can execute SQL-side?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported, but should be quite easy to implement. Can you please open an issue requesting this on https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL?

In the meantime, as a workaround, you can use [raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) to invoke the function, and then compose over that with LINQ if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
Submitted an issue: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/669